# Jenkins - Git client plugin throwing Http-503 error when it is connecting through HTTP proxy

Tags: jenkins-plugins

some thing weird thing happened to my Jenkins setup and killing me for whole day to solve the issue.

I have Jenkins job setup which connects to git repository on remote server through Http proxy. Below are the details

Jenkins Version: 1.527

Git client plugin : 1.9.1

Git plugin : 2.2.2

It was working fine for more than a month without any issue. But started giving Http 503 error when it try to pull the latest changes from that repository recently.

Below is the error:

> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>
> > git.exe config remote.origin.url `https://<userName>:<Passwd>@<giturl>`
>
> Fetching upstream changes from `https://<userName>@<giturl>`
>
> > git.exe --version FATAL: Failed to fetch from `https://<userName>@<giturl>`
>
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from
>   `https://<userName>@<giturl>`   at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)   at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)   at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1408)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
>   at
>   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88) 
>   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1597)   at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247) Caused by:
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to connect to
>   `https://<userName>@<giturl>` (status = 503)
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.checkCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1978)

Comment: Upon debugging the git client plugin code base, CliGitAPIImpl.java
Proxy credentials are null, Not setting proxy credentails
Checking http client:https://<url>/info/refs
Executed:GET https://<url>/info/refs HTTP/1.1
status:503
Checking http client:https://<url>/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
Executed:GET https://<url>/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
status:503
FATAL: Failed to fetch from https://<url>
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://<url>
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:622)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working with my network team, it is a issue with Http Proxy. I was asked to use git:// instead of https:// in the github URL. It works great now.